# Все задачи помечаются выполненными при клике на чекбокс

Tags: javascript, jquery

Недавно начал изучать jquery и возникла проблема. Есть список дел, если кликнуть на чекбокс "вополнено" зачеркиваются все дела.Мне не приходит в голову как это можно реализовать. При снятии флажка задача должна становится опять не зачеркнутой. Код прилагаю. HTML в нем нет, не пугайтесь, такая задача.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('<fieldset>').appendTo('body');
$('<div>').addClass('table-title').appendTo('fieldset');
$('<h3>Список: </h3>').appendTo('.table-title');
$('<div>').appendTo('.table-title');
$('<label>Дело: </label>').appendTo('.table-title > div');
$('<input></input>').attr('id', 'text').attr('type', 'text').appendTo('label');
$('<input></input>').attr('id', 'plus').attr('type', 'button').attr('value', 'Добавить').appendTo('label');
$('<table>').height('auto').attr('id', 'myTable').addClass('table-fill').appendTo('fieldset');
$('<tr>').appendTo('table');
$('<th>№</th>').addClass('list_link').appendTo('tr');
$('<th>Описание</th>').addClass('list_link').appendTo('tr');
$('<th>Действие</th>').addClass('list_link').appendTo('tr');

var number = 0;

    $('#plus').click(function(){
        number++;
        var task = $('#text').val();

        $('<tr>').appendTo('table');
        $('<th></th>').text(number).appendTo('tr:last-child');
        $('<th></th>').text(task).addClass('task').appendTo('tr:last-child');
        $('<th></th>').appendTo('tr:last-child');
        $('<label>Выполнено</label>').appendTo('tr:last-child > th:last-child');
        $('<input>').attr('type', 'checkbox').appendTo('tr:last-child > th:last-child');

        $('input[type = checkbox]').click(function(){
            if ($('input:checkbox:checked')) {
                $('.task').addClass('thro');
            }
        })
    });
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все чекбоксы на странице:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]')
```

Все чекбоксы внутри el:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]', el)
el.find('input[type=checkbox]')
```

---

В Вашем случае, Вам нужно добавлять класс не всем, а только нужным элементам.
Например, `$('.task', $(this).parent()).addClass('thro')`

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, но все еще не получается или я чего-то не понял.
Что не так с этой функцией?

   $('input[type=checkbox]', 'tr').click(function(){
    $('.task', $(this).parent()).addClass('thro');
   })

Comment: `if (this.checked) { $(this).closest("tr").find(".task").addClass("thro"); }`

Comment: @vp_arth Там получается на два уровня надо подняться.

Comment: igor, работает, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Вы, вероятно, имели в виду создавать элементы `td` внутри строк таблицы.

Второе. Нет необходимости назначать обработчики `click` каждый раз, когда создается новая строка. Более того, в Вашем коде новый обработчик каждый раз *добавляется* всем существующим в данный момент чекбоксам. Следует использовать делегирование:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  ...
  // один раз, в конце $(document).ready, когда myTable уже существует
  $("#myTable").on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
    if (this.checked) { 
      $(this).closest("tr").find(".task").addClass("thro"); 
    } else {
      $(this).closest("tr").find(".task").removeClass("thro"); 
    }
  });
});
```